# User is not redirected to their respective bank account page while doing transaction on Razorpay?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, razorpay

We are using razorpay as a payment gateway for handling the online payments on our website.

The problem is that some of our customers are not able to complete their transactions as when they select a payment mode (net banking or card payment) they are redirected to a blank window (with URL about:blank)

Ideally, they should be redirected to their respective bank accounts login. 
For some customers, everything is working fine and they are able to do their transactions so we do not thing the problem is with integration.

User experience for the user:

1. User selects online payment
2. A dialog is popped up handled by Razorpay.
3. User selects a payment mode.
4. User clicks on the Pay button
5. User should be redirected to their bank accounts login.
6. User logs in and does a transaction

From step 2-5 is handled by razorpay.

I tried contacting their support team but they are not able to figure out the reason for the issue along with any solution.

Please share if anyone has experienced a similar issue and what was the solution for it.

I am considering that there might be some issue on the clients browser(some pop-up blocker or something)

Thank you for your help.

```
var _this$state2 = _this.state,
          shipping = _this$state2.shipping,
          billing = _this$state2.billing;
      var options = {
        key: _env.default.rzpKey,
        amount: _this.total * 100,
        // 2000 paise = INR 20, amount in paisa
        // currency: 'USD',
        name: _env.default.siteTitle,
        description: 'Your Order',
        image: '/static/logo-accent.png',
        /* Below Hnadler is called when the transaction is successful  */
        handler: function handler(response) {
          /* Create Order is called when the transaction is successful*/
          _this.createOrder(response, _this.state.cod);
        },
        prefill: {
          name: billing.firstName || shipping.firstName,
          email: billing.email || shipping.email,
          contact: billing.phone || shipping.phone
        },
        theme: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      };
      var rzp = new Razorpay(options); // eslint-disable-line
// Razorpay dialog is opened
      rzp.open();
```

Comment: Until you don`t post your code , we won`t be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for replying @PrabhjotSinghKainth
There is no specific code snippet which handles this cycle. Once the Razorpay dialog opens everything related to the payment is handled by them.
We only provide a callback function on initializing the dialog which is fired if the transaction is completed.

Error occurs when the customer selects a payment mode and proceed with transaction. they are then redirected to a new window which is blank.

Comment: There must be an error in your code or some configuration error. Until you don`t post your code, we cannot help you.'

Comment: Hi @PrabhjotSinghKainth

Please find the code snippet which is responsible for intializing the razorpay dialog along with the options passed as arguements for the dialog